# Black screen after splash screen

Tags: debian, memory, out-of-memory, gdm3

Im using Debian 10 Buster GNOME Editon. Yesterday I met with this issue. After I boot Debian, the splash screen comes correctly, but after that it simply gets stuck (ie becones a still image) and after few minutes cursor appears at bottom. Then after few minutes the screen goes black. Thats it.

What could be the issue? Is it any memory issue or graphics related??

(Windows works fine tho)...
(Is such a question allowed here or better migrate to Ask Ubuntu?? But I use Debian :p)

Edit 1 :
After half an hour, the screen was flushed with texts few of which were like "Out of memory kill cron or sacrifice..." so I suppose that its a memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something is using all your RAM/Memory causing the OS to go into Out Of Memory state, which will start killing programs/processes to keep the OS alive, see the link below for more info. Try to boot into rescue/single-user mode and disable some on boot programs to see if that helps.

https://www.memset.com/docs/additional-information/oom-killer/

Comment: Ok I will check the docs and see if they help. Thanks.

Comment: Rescue mode also suffers from the same issue